# How to keep my fork updated with the changes at the main base as I keep my local additions to the project?

Tags: git, github

Presently I forked a project at Github and adding some new features to it. However, it is really active project and codes are always changing around. How should I keep my forked local copy up to date as I do not lose my changes?

From my search I guess I should use `git fetch` command and stay away `git pull` since fetching just takes the commits that are not related to my improvements but pull gets all the changes and merges the changes with my local copy. Am I right that the fetch command is the solution?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I update a forked project, on git, to the original/master copy?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7297486/can-i-update-a-forked-project-on-git-to-the-original-master-copy)

Answer (score 0):

[`git fetch`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch) will update your [remote tracking branches](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4697054/6309), but you won't know if your current branch is still compatible.

It is best to rebase your branch on top of `upstream/master`, with `upstream` being a remote referencing the original repo you have cloned.
See "[Pull new updates from original Github repository into forked Github repository](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3903835/6309)".

You can [combine the two (fetch+rebase) with a `git pull --rebase`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26773064/6309)

```
git checkout yourPRbranch
git pull --rebase upstream master
```

Comment: Note: this assume that you are doing your "local addition" in a separate branch, not in one already common with the original repo, like '`master`'.